# Does the Book of Revelation indicate whether human souls will be fighting during Armageddon?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, revelation, catholic-bible

I am a Catholic and I would like to know if the Book of Revelation in the Catholic Bible (or in other Christian Bibles) has anything to say about whether human souls will be fighting during Armageddon.

For example, are there any passage(s) in the Book of Revelation that indicate that the human souls that went to Heaven will be fighting alongside God's angels against the demons and the human souls that went to Hell?

Does the Book of Revelation indicate whether human souls will be fighting during Armageddon?

Comment: There is nothing anywhere in the Bible that says that human souls go to heaven.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth   - How do you understand Rev. 9:9
'And when He had opened the fifth seal, I saw under the altar the souls of them that were slain for the Word of God, and for the testimony which they held.'

Comment: @DanFefferman. In Genesis 4:10, Abel's blood cries from the ground.
Revelation 6:9's fifth seal is symbolic of those that die during the Tribulation. Dead souls can't speak any more than blood can cry. 
6:11 goes on to describe them as "resting" (i.e. unconscious, awaiting the resurrection).
And, more significantly, notice that all the seals are about events that take place on Earth, not Heaven.

Comment: @RayButterworth: Didn't your first comment under this posting go a little too far? Don't souls go to heaven?  I thought that "absent from the body is present with the Lord" (Philippians 1:20-24). Clarification, please. Don

Comment: @rhetorician, "*absent from the body is present with the Lord*" is from 2 Corinthians 5:8.
That chapter doesn't mention "soul", and mentions heaven only near the beginning: "*with our house which is from heaven*".
Notice that it says the house is **from** heaven.
There's nothing there (or anywhere else) that implies that souls go to heaven.
¶ Look through all four Gospels for "heaven". If you treat Matthew's "kingdom of heaven" as "kingdom of God" and ignore where "heaven" refers to the atmosphere, there is almost no mention of heaven in the Gospels, and definitely no humans going there.

Comment: @rhetorician asks "*Didn't you … go a little too far?*". As a Catholic you believe that people have immortal souls that go to Heaven or Hell after death. The Church doesn't get  its knowledge from only the Bible, but the question asks specifically about the book of Revelation, which does not teach about immortal souls or people going to heaven. ¶ But yes, according to the Bible, human souls will be fighting, here on Earth, and they will be the mortal souls that you and I currently are. People *are* souls. "man *became* a living soul" Gen 2:7. "the soul that sinneth, it shall *die*" Eze 18:4.

Comment: @RayButterworth, there is at least one mention in the Gospels of a soul going to Heaven. Recall the conversation between Jesus and the two men who were crucified with Him... "Then he said, “Jesus, remember me when you come into your kingdom.” He replied to him, “Amen, I say to you, today you will be with me in Paradise." - Luke 23: 42-43

Comment: @user57467, "*I say to you **,** today you will be with me in Paradise*" has a misplaced comma, supplied by the translators. "*I say to you today **,** you will be with me in Paradise*" makes more sense. Jesus didn't go to Paradise that day; he went to hell. This was a response to "*remember me **when** thou comest into thy kingdom*", and Jesus replied that he didn't need to wait until then, he could confirm it now. Years later, John 3:13 confirmed that "*no man hath ascended up to heaven, but  [Jesus]*".

Comment: @RayButterworth, why would God send Jesus to Earth to save sinners if God didn't want any human soul, except the soul of Jesus, to go to Heaven? That viewpoint doesn't make any sense to me. No, I believe that the end result of Jesus's mission on Earth was to open the doors of Heaven to all human souls, at least for those who live a good and righteous life.

Comment: @RayButterworth: Thanks for the correction about 2 Cor 5:8, not Philippians 1:20-24, being the verse I was thinking about. I would not, however, dismiss the Phil 1 passage, since it does say that Paul desires to depart and be with Christ. As for Revelation, I think the apostle John's experience of seeing an open door in heaven and hearing a voice saying “Come up here, and I will show you what must take place after this” indicates that the "come up" meant "come up [to heaven]."  John then said, "At once I was in the Spirit, and there before me was a throne in heaven with someone sitting on it."

Comment: @RayButterworth: Also, the apostle Paul's description of his being "caught up into the third heaven" is an indication that a person can enter heaven and can be enabled to hear "inexpressible things." Of course Paul wasn't sure if his entire being--body and spirit--or just his spirit was caught up (2 Cor 12:2). Moreover, in 2 Cor 5, Paul talks of being naked and awaiting the resurrection of the body so that the body can be clothed. What is clothed, if not the soul that exists in heaven until resurrection Day? Question: Are you even WILLING to concede you MIGHT be wrong in your belief? Don

Comment: @rhetorician asks "*Are you even WILLING to concede you MIGHT be wrong in your belief?*". I'm always willing and thankful to be proven wrong. But my belief on this is 1) The Bible nowhere says that people have immortal souls or that they will go to heaven, and 2) Catholicism teaches that people have immortal souls that go to Heaven or Hell at death, and it claims that this knowledge is based on Church tradition and other non-biblical sources. It would be difficult to disprove either of these. My opinion is that *sola scriptura* Protestants should not follow the non-biblical Catholic doctrines.

Comment: @user57467 says "*Jesus's mission on Earth was to open the doors of Heaven to all human souls*". I'm not arguing overall purpose, only the use of "soul" and that the Bible says that any human but Jesus has ever gone to heaven (versus a vision thereof). The Bible mentions a future general resurrection at Jesus's return, and another, much larger resurrection following the Millennium, both here on Earth, not in Heaven. I'm not saying Catholics are wrong, only that their belief is *not* strictly based on the Bible, nor do they claim it is. The Q wants Biblical support for non-Biblical doctrine.

Comment: **To clarify**. The OP asked for biblical support for a Catholic belief.
Unlike most Protestant organizations, the Catholic Church is quite open about some of its doctrines' being based on Church Tradition, new revelation, and other non-biblical sources.
My intent was simply to point out that that the idea of human souls currently living in heaven is one of the Catholic Church's non-Biblical beliefs, and so the Book of Revelation won't provide details about such things, which is what the OP was looking for. I was *not* saying that Catholics are wrong to believe what their Church teaches.

Comment: @RayButterworth: Oh, I forgot. Jesus said to his disciples, "I go to prepare a place for you . . ., so that where I am you may be also." Where else could that meeting take place?  Yup, your mind is c-l-o-s-e-d.

Comment: @rhetorician says "*where I am*". Yup, it's either:
1) On Earth where Jesus has just returned from Heaven:
"*For the Lord himself shall **descend from heaven** … and the [elect] shall be caught up together with them in the clouds, to meet the Lord in the air …*".
(1Thessalonians 4:16–17);
Or 2) On Earth where Jesus has been ruling throughout the Millennium:
"*… the name of the city of my God, which is new Jerusalem, which cometh **down out of heaven** …*" (Revelation 3:12);
"*And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down from God **out of heaven** …*" (Revelation 21:2).

Comment: @RayButterworth. OK, but where does the marriage supper of the Lamb take place? I think it takes place in heaven after the Church Universal is caught up to meet the Lord in the air. When the Church has departed the earth, the Great Tribulation will take place. When King Jesus wraps up the Tribulation, perhaps THEN the new Jerusalem descends FROM Heaven. Are there any resurrected believers in that heavenly/earthly city? I think so.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth, what do you mean that the Bible never mentions human souls going to heaven? Isn't that the reason why Jesus came to this Earth?

Comment: @TobyHarnish  In comments above, Ray Butterworth has argued against that mainstream Christian belief. While your question to him is understandable, it will get nowhere, only prolonging this already absurdly long list of comments. Moderators will remove the whole lot, any day now. Comments are only to remark on a Q or an A, not on other comments by others. Comments are not for diving off into areas not directly related to the actual Q, which arguing about what 'soul' means is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revelation gives multiple views of the same events. Each section backs up and adds new details to what has already been disclosed. That is why establishing a timeline and master sequence is so baffling. The battle of Armageddon is one of those events. It is announced at one point, but the actual battle is described in Revelation 19.

> 11 Then I saw heaven opened, and behold, a white horse! The one
> sitting on it is called Faithful and True, and in righteousness he
> judges and makes war. 12 His eyes are like a flame of fire, and on his
> head are many diadems, and he has a name written that no one knows but
> himself. 13 He is clothed in a robe dipped in blood, and the name
> by which he is called is The Word of God. 14 **And the armies of heaven**,
> arrayed in fine linen, white and pure, were following him on white
> horses. 15 From his mouth comes a sharp sword with which to strike
> down the nations, and he will rule them with a rod of iron. He will
> tread the winepress of the fury of the wrath of God the Almighty. 16
> On his robe and on his thigh he has a name written, King of kings and
> Lord of lords.
>
> 17 Then I saw an angel standing in the sun, and with a loud voice he
> called to all the birds that fly directly overhead, “Come, gather for
> the great supper of God, 18 to eat the flesh of kings, the flesh of
> captains, the flesh of mighty men, the flesh of horses and their
> riders, and the flesh of all men, both free and slave, both small
> and great.” 19 And I saw the beast and the kings of the earth with
> their armies gathered to make war against him who was sitting on the
> horse and against **his army**. 20 And the beast was captured, and with it
> the false prophet who in its presence had done the signs by which
> he deceived those who had received the mark of the beast and those who
> worshiped its image. These two were thrown alive into the lake of fire
> that burns with sulfur. 21 And the rest were slain by the sword that
> came from the mouth of him who was sitting on the horse, and all the
> birds were gorged with their flesh. (Revelation 19:11-21)

As you can see, there is an army of heaven to accompany Jesus. All we know is that they ride white horses (possibly symbolic) and wear white robes (which symbolizes purity). There are Christian martyrs described in Revelation 7 as having washed their robes in the blood of the lamb. Thus it is likely though not certain that the army is made up of those martyred during the tribulation.

Comment: How can we be sure this is a Catholic answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is no description, in ch16, of any battle at Armageddon. "The kings of the whole world" gather for the battle in v16, then the narrative is paused while the vision describes the Harlot. The next actual event in the narrative after ch16 is the return of Christ (ch19 v11) accompanied by all the power of heaven, as in Matthew ch24 v30. I suggest, then, that the Return of Christ IS the battle of Armageddon, from God's side.

We need to be wary of taking too literally all the details of the visions of Revelation. Some of them are best taken as metaphor, and I believe that includes the concept of "fighting" in that last battle. In reality, the moment when Christ appears "on the clouds of heaven in power and great glory" and God puts out his full strength should surely be enough in itself to disable all human strength to resist. No armies and allies needed. I suggest that the battle will be over "in the twinkling of an eye".

Comment: + 1 -- You make an important point in saying that the narrative pauses immediately after the troops mass for battle (16:16). But ch 19 may refer back to this.  "The armies of heaven followed him, mounted on white horses and wearing clean white linen. Out of his mouth came a sharp sword to strike the nations."

Comment: How can we be sure this is a Catholic answer?

Comment: My apologies, it wasn't meant to be a Catholic answer.  Since one of the tags was "Revelation", I was offering a "student of Revelation" answer. I wasn't intending to mislead anyone. P.S. The OP did say "or any other Christian Bible", so a Catholic answer wasn't really specified.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli I get it.   This site used to think scoping was necessary and asking for answers from all Christians was too broad   Now it seems no rules apply.  This is just another forum

Answer (score 1):

The stage is set for the Battle of Armageddon in Revelation 16:12-16:

> <sup>**12**</sup> The sixth angel emptied his bowl on the great river Euphrates. Its water was dried up to prepare the way for the kings of the East. <sup>**13**</sup> I saw three unclean spirits like frogs come from the mouth of the dragon, from the mouth of the beast, and from the mouth of the false prophet. <sup>**14**</sup> These were demonic spirits who performed signs. They went out to the kings of the whole world to assemble them for the battle on the great day of God the almighty. <sup>**15**</sup> (“Behold, I am coming like a thief.” Blessed is the one who watches and keeps his clothes ready, so that he may not go naked and people see him exposed.) <sup>**16**</sup> They then assembled the kings in the place that is named Armageddon in Hebrew.

No description of the battle follows until Revelation 19:11, 12, 17-21 (assuming that this refers to Armageddon):

> <sup>**11**</sup> Then I saw the heavens opened, and there was a white horse; its rider was [called] “Faithful and True.” He judges and wages war in righteousness. <sup>**12**</sup> ... He had a name inscribed that no one knows except himself. ... <sup>**17**</sup> Then I saw an angel standing on the sun. He cried out a loud voice to all the birds flying high overhead, “Come here. Gather for God’s great feast, <sup>**18**</sup> to eat the flesh of kings, the flesh of military officers, and the flesh of warriors, the flesh of horses and of their riders, and the flesh of all, free and slave, small and great.” <sup>**19**</sup> Then I saw the beast and the kings of the earth and their armies gathered to fight against the one riding the horse and against his army. <sup>**20**</sup> The beast was caught and with it the false prophet who had performed in its sight the signs by which he led astray those who had accepted the mark of the beast and those who had worshiped its image. The two were thrown alive into the fiery pool burning with sulfur. <sup>**21**</sup> The rest were killed by the sword that came out of the mouth of the one riding the horse, and all the birds gorged themselves on their flesh.

Human souls are not described as being directly involved. However, they are indeed mentioned as interested parties.

Revelation 6:9-11 NABRE

> <sup>**9**</sup> When he broke open the fifth seal, I saw underneath the altar the souls of those who had been slaughtered because of the witness they bore to the word of God. <sup>**10**</sup> They cried out in a loud voice, “How long will it be, holy and true master, before you sit in judgment and avenge our blood on the inhabitants of the earth? <sup>**11**</sup> Each of them was given a white robe, and they were told to be patient a little while longer until the number was filled of their fellow servants and brothers who were going to be killed as they had been.

**Summary**: As others have pointed out, the battle may be symbolic. This seems especially likely in that the enemies of God are nearly all killed by the sword that comes out of the mouth of the Rider, probably representing God's word. However, the battle's literal description implies that it takes place on earth, where rivers are dried up to make way for eastern kings and birds devour the flesh of the losing army. Spiritual forces are certainly at work, but there is no direct mention of human souls being involved except as passionately interested watchers.

**Conclusion**: there is no mention of human souls being directly involved in the battle of Armageddon.

Comment: How can we be sure this is a Catholic answer?

Comment: Your priest is a good place to start to check if the answer conforms. Catholic tradition is open to various interpretations of Revelation. See [this article](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/what-is-the-battle-of-armageddon). As far as the Bible quotes go, they are taken from an edition approved for Catholics. [Here](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/revelation/0) is a link to the introduction FYI, but it doesn't deal directly with your question.

Comment: @User 14 There are 18 pages of text in the  Catholic Concise Sacramentum Mundi Encyclopedia of Theology, Ed. Karl Rahner, under the heading Revelation. The relevant bit is sub-heading B Theological Interpretation p.1460-1466, then IV. Private Revelation p.1471-1473. Far too much to explain. Suffice to quote the last sentence: "A theology of private revelation would have to study it within the framework of the charismatic element in the Church." ...

Comment: Whereas Protestant groups offer myriad private interpretation re. this Q, Catholicism is much more cautious. If it has not made a pronouncement on whether human souls will be fighting at Armageddon, it's unlikely that any individual Catholic would venture to do so. But if a quote could be found from Catholic literature that is acceptable within the charismatic element in the Church, that could give you a Catholic answer. I just wouldn't hold my breath waiting for that, if I was you!

Comment: @ Anne.  “What makes a well supported answer?”   The info you point to would make the answer better